# Ruby on Rails: How to "check-out" a model value

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm new at this so please excuse the lack of terminology as well as experience.

If you don't want to read the whole explanation below here's the short of what I'm trying to do:

- Users on my site give feedback on each other's songs
- Two users should not be able to give feedback on the same song at the same time

So, I want to put in place some sort of "check-out" system where a user checks out a song to give it feedback. So if one user checks out a song, another user won't be able to access it. Also, if the user who checks out the song leaves feedback - the song will return to it's non checked out state. If the user doesn't leave feedback and leaves the page, the song will return to its unchecked out state.

That's the short version, here's the long version:

I have a website where I want people to trade feedback on each others songs, however they can only receive as much feedback as they give. To do this I have a page I call "feed".

When someone visits this page, they are showed a song and are given a form to leave feedback. If they leave feedback, they earn one feedback for their own song to receive.

I do this in the controller with:

```
@track = Track.where.not(user_id: current_user.id).
               where.not(id: current_user.feeds.select(:track_id)).
               where("tracks.feed_avaliable > '0'").
               where("pref_genre = #{current_user.genre_id} OR genre_wait <= ?", ((Time.now.to_i - Track.last.last_feed.to_i) / 3600)).
               reorder(feed_level: :asc, last_feed: :desc, created_at: :asc).
               first()
```

Which hopefully works out to, find the first track/song where the user of the track is not the current user, where the current user has not previously left a feed(back), where the feed available is > 0, where there tracks preferred genre is the current users genre or the genre wait time is greater than the time since the last feed. Sort the tracks in order of feed level smallest to largest, last fed the longest ago to the soonest, created at the longest ago to the soonest.

Anyways, now I'm stuck on the issue of what if two people end up giving feedback on the same track at the same time.

This is why I want some sort of "check-out" method for the tracks. So that if a user is currently giving feedback on a track, another user won't get served that track from the formula above.

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could create a boolean field on the `Song` model called something like 'checked_out'. Create a controller method to check out the song or include code to set the `checked_out` field in whatever controller method is checking it out. After creating the boolean field Rails will generate a method `checked_out?` which you can use to determine if a song is checked out, and whether to allow another user to check it out.

```
...
@song = Song.find(params[:id])
unless @song.checked_out?
  @song.update_attribute :checked_out, true
end
...
```

You will want to watch out that you don't allow users to check out songs forever - if a user checks out a song and then walks away and never comes back, you will want to have a process that checks it back in at some point.

If, as you progress, you find yourself adding a lot of boolean fields around the song's checked-out status, that might indicate that a state machine is an appropriate solution.

It would also be helpful to create a scope in the model file for `Song` to get songs that are not checked out:

```
scope :not_checked_out, -> { where checked_out: false }
```

Use this if you only want to show songs that are not checked out - of course you still want to check in the controller as well, in the event that a song is checked out by another user after the page is rendered.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the response I think this is getting me on my way.

Two questions. 1: if a user checks out a song, I would only want him to see that song until it's checked out. Is there anyway to relate the two? 2: How would I ensure a user doesn't checkout a song indefinitely? A cron job? Or maybe javascript on the page that unchecks it if the page closes? Thanks for your help!

Comment: I've updated my answer to address the question of displaying only songs that are not checked out. As for the cleanup of abandoned check outs, there are a couple options - a periodic cron job is a good option if you are dealing with a large data set. If your data set is fairly small you could just do the update to check them back in before pulling the list of songs for display. This would slow page loads, so should be a temporary solution for early stages of development.

Comment: Alright thanks that's helpful, I'm 90% there now. Just need to deal with the indefinitely checking out issue. One thing I had to change that you didn't mention in your answer though was that I had to add a @song.save after changing the checkout variable to make it update in the database.

Comment: sorry about that! I updated my answer to use `update_attribute` which updates and saves the value.

Comment: Thanks! Also I think I just figured out a way to stop the checked out indefinitely issue. I've created a checked_out and a check_out_time variable to the Song model, and a song_checked_out variable to the User. In the controller, the logic first checks to see if the user has a song checked out, and the time difference between now and the checkout time is less then 10 min. If it is, it just serves him that song. If not, it goes to the regular song selection process which part of it is checking whether a song is checked out or the difference between now and the checkout time is more than 10 min

Comment: Hopefully that makes sense, I was trying to keep it in that one comment.